# How to install my netgear wnda3100v2

Tags: wireless, networking, netgear

(I posted this with my brother's ubuntu computer) Before you start telling me to do stuff take note that I'm twelve so I do not have access to a-lot. My computer has ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

when i use lsusb in the terminal,(I'm only typing the port that has the adapter)

```
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0846:9011 NetGear, inc. WNDA3100v2 802.11abgn [Broadcom BCM4323]
```

anyway I can set this up so I can get a network connection out of it, and keep in mind that I have no internet connection right now